# I'm trying to use git add . in terminal for a GitHub repo of a Unity project and I keep getting this error: fatal: adding files failed. How do I fix?

Tags: git, github, terminal

I have tried to get the files to be added for quite a while now, and whenever I try it, I get the error. It is a rather large Unity project but I wouldn't think that should be a problem as the whole folder is no larger than a couple of gigabytes. I am rather new to using GitHub in terminal, sorry if any questions I ask are dumb. If anyone could help, that would be great!

I am using git version 2.40.1.windows.1.

I have tried git add . multiple times, and it keeps running through the list of files and at what seems to be the end sends out the error. I have tried cd NextFolder and config core.autocrlf false, but neither of them are working.

Comment: Please copy the exact git output and paste it in the question.